# D3.js How to add tooltip in my legend using line graph

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I draw a line graph using D3.js and i am using tooltip in line graph,but i am also using tooltip in legends but enable to show the tooltip in legends,i wrote given code,it is possible to  show the tooltip in legends.

```
   var dates=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31];
var legend = canvas.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
   // .attr("transform", "translate(70,10)");
var legendRect = legend.selectAll('rect').data(dates);
legendRect.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function (d,i){return i*14;})
    .attr("width", 12)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .style("fill","steelblue")
 legend.selectAll("text")
.data(dates)
.enter()
.append("text")  
.attr("x", function (d,i){return i*14;}) 
.attr("y", 25)
.attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
.attr("font-size", "11px")
.attr("fill", "white")
.text(function(d) {
return d;
})
.on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(formatTime(d.key) + "<br/>"  + d.value)  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });

Iam adding tooltip in text but enable to show the tooltip in my values(I have only problem in legend tooltip)
```

Comment: Could you provide enough code to reproduce your problem?  The code above doesn't run.

Comment: I have Problem only tooltip of legend,it is possible to add tooltip also legend.

Comment: I understood your question.  I see in the code above that you are handling a `mouseover`  in the legend to show your "tooltip" div.  Obviously this code isn't working.  So, being the nice StackOverflow user I am, I went to debug your code.  **BUT** the above code doesn't run, too many undefined variables.  At that point I can no longer help you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://gist.github.com/bobmonteverde/2070123) code. It does exactly what you want.

[This](http://bl.ocks.org/Matthew-Weber/5645518) is also a great example.